# Run a program in a different thread from OSX command line?

Tags: multithreading, macos, shell, command-line

I'm developing a node.js server application. To speed up the process, I've configured my editor so it will run the current file with the command `node <current_file>` when I press a key. The problem is: the editor blocks when the file starts a server. How can I change that command so it runs node.js on background?

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Comment: VIM, it does not work on it.

Comment: @bamboon why you posted a perfectly good answer as a comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start it asynchronously by adding an `&` at the end:

`node <current_file> &`

Comment: I'm accepting because this is the right answer. Strangely does not work on VIM for some reason!